# Is it possible for an application (written in Mono C#) to run a console command?

Tags: command-line, application-development, mono, c#

I am wondering if a Mono C# application running in Ubuntu can somehow run a terminal command. For example, could the user give the program his or her password and then have the application run

`sudo apt-get install application-name`

(console requests password)

`password`

(console requests confirmation)

`y`

Preferably, this would be done without actually opening a terminal visible to the user, so that the application could provide the necessary feedback and manage the whole operation cleanly with as little user interaction as possible.

Is there a way to do that? If so, how? Let me know if clarification is needed. Thank you!

Comment: This question is specifically related to Linux, namely Ubuntu, therefore, this is an appropriate place to post this question. I appreciate the downvote based on your tentative opinion regarding classification however.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method is the same for the *nix'es so it should go on [unix.SE] or even Stack Overflow as it is about programming. Sorry.

Comment: Other questions of this nature are allowed, so this one should be, too.

Comment: "Development on Ubuntu" is explicitly ontopic in the FAQ, voting to reopen.

Comment: Could you share a link to the question on SO?

Comment: @flimm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736891/run-command-from-within-c-sharp-mono-application-in-linux

Comment: too localized ha, I love it when I find a askubuntu question which exactly matches my need and it is closed, because apparently it is unlikely to help me. I'm so glad you made that decision on my behalf.

Comment: I'm with you trampster.  This is another example of a bunch of moderators doing to much moderating.